# How to disable prompting for opening specific file types?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

I often receive diff files (*.diff) as attachments, as part of our team workflow, and need to view them. To do so, I double-click the attachment to open it in an external viewer program.

Outlook always prompts me to confirm whether I want to open these files. I *do*. However, the checkbox is disabled, so I cannot uncheck it.

[image: Outlook prompt with disabled checkbox]

**Is there a way to disable these prompts for only the *.diff file type?** I don't mind having it prompt me for other file types.

I looked through all the settings in Outlook but couldn't find a place to configure this.

Using MS Outlook 2013 / Windows 7.

Comment: Start outlook as administrátor then set it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start outlook as administrator then set it.

Changing `Always ask before opening this type of file` requires write to registry that requires administrator privilege.